# Switched outlet wiring

Tags: electrical

I replaced a switched outlet together with a switch, but the outlet that is supposed to be controlled by the switch stopped working. I was trying to be careful to attach all the wires to the same connectors, but I must have messed something up. Could you please take a look at the pictures below to guess what I did wrong?

Switch:
[image]

Outlet (tab is broken):
[image]
With this set up, I have both, lower and upper, outlets permanently on and none of them is controlled by the switch. What did I do wrong?

Comment: For safety, the wires under the screws are not properly attached, the wires need to be fully under the screws, too much bare wire exposed. The red wire on the switch has a cut installation.  The wires on the push in connections need to be pushed in with no bare wire exposed.

Comment: You didn't remove the tab on the other side of the outlet did you???

Comment: What is a 'cut installation'?

Comment: I did remove the tab on the other side of the outlet? Could it be also the cause for the second issue with other outlets and switches not working downstairs?

Comment: If those whites (commons) were previously wire nutted together or connected by the tab separating them might be why you lost power downstream. The pic looks like it's a single pole switch but please confirm that it is.

Comment: I went ahead and installed a new outlet with just one tab broken (between red and black). No both lower and upper outlets are permanently on and are not controlled by the switch. Is my switch wiring wrong? Yes, it is a single pole switch

Comment: A voltmeter would be helpful to measure power at various points. The assumption is that the red wire at the switch goes to the switched outlet. You should carefully test for current at the switch at the red wire terminal with the switch on and then off. That should confirm whether or not the switch is functioning properly. If it is then check current in the red wire at the receptacle with the switch on and off.

Comment: look closely at the red wire to the switch, the red insulation has a cut along the length of the wire.  "spell checker is changing the word on me"

Comment: Please don't change anything in the setup. Trying things will only complicate finding a solution and could be unsafe.

Comment: Have you replaced any other outlets in this room?